# Calculating mean of true ground points in every pixel of DEM using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem

I have a DEM of 12m resolution and true ground points (more than 11,0000 points) to assess this DEM.

I want to take the  mean from all points within every pixel using ArcGIS Pro.

How can I do this?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. We are not a tutorial site, but a problem-solving one. If you do some research, locate a tutorial, make an attempt, and encounter an error, *then* GIS SE would be a good place to post the issue (with a complete description of what you were attempting when the problem was encountered).

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS, ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: Any of them especially ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro

Comment: Zonal statistics in QGIS seems like what you are after